# easy way to plot combined model in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I have a data-set which has 3 columns: `date, amount`, and a `factor/cluster`. For example:

```
date;amount;cluster_id
02.10.10;-13,86;3
04.10.10;-66,28;3
06.10.10;-14,99;3
25.10.10;-20,96;3
30.10.10;-408,99;3
31.01.11;-29,5;2
07.02.11;-652,85;3
19.09.11;-277,48;3
30.09.11;-6,18;3
03.10.11;-242,47;3
04.11.11;-299,77;3
20.02.12;-367,85;3
03.10.12;-4,99;4
13.09.13;-6,59;4
14.10.13;-1043,46;3
24.10.13;-373,99;3
24.10.13;-1321,91;3
18.12.13;-24,45;4
03.02.14;-66,87;3
30.08.14;-7,6;2
28.10.14;-115;3
13.12.14;-8,99;3
15.12.14;-352,44;3
19.12.14;115;3
08.07.15;-59;2
```

The following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=amount, colour=factor(mycluster))) +
stat_smooth(method = "rlm", formula = y ~ x)
```

simply performs a `rlm` per group/factor. And looks like:
[image: Plot of Regression per cluster]

How can I combine each separate regression model into one big (added) model in order to plot one "combined" model in an easy way e.g. without looping over all the rlm models manually.

Comment: [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `+ stat_smooth(method = "rlm", formula = y ~ x, aes(color = NULL))`? I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: I edited the question. Do you understand it now @Roland?

Comment: Well, does my comment answer your question?

Comment: not really you perform a rlm of ALL the data, but what I was rather up to is to perform a regression for EACH and than add each result into one big model.

Comment: @geoHeil what does your model look like? How do you combine three regressions into one model?

Comment: As I am mostly interested in the forecast I compute each forecast and then add these amounts to one "final" amount. But I was hoping there is a better way to do it.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you want to do (not even if you want to plot or the numeric values). Voting to close.

Comment: ok - I close it however I only see the delete link and not the http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question no longer relevant link.